# spark close() cause the cache to be cleared automatically?

Tags: apache-spark

I know spark.catalog.clearCache() used to clear the cache explicitly.
but I'm wondering if it automatically clears Spark's cache when I call spark.close().

Looking forward to reply, your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark points to the SparkSession which means when you do spark.close() your closing that session.
After calling spark.close() if you want to perform any transformation or action you need to recreate that SparkSession and then only you can work.

But in case of spark.catalog.clearCache() if will only clear the cached table.

Long story short:
spark.catalog.clearCache() : Clear the cached table.
spark.close() : close the spark session
both has differnt work you need to it based on usecse.

Comment: So, when the spark session is done by calling spark.close(), will the cached table disappear from memory as well even if I don't call spark.catalog.clearCache()? I'm wondering when the cache piled up by Spark's cache() disappears from memory.

Comment: Yes, when you call spark.close() so you're ultimately closing the spark application which means all intermediate and cached data will be removed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started StackOverflow, so I can't upvote because of my lack of reputation. If that becomes possible, I will definitely come to upvote.